# Angular2: straightforward binding

Tags: angular

I've created a component with a property which is initialized on `ngOnInit`:

```
@Component({
  //...
})
export class Validate implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private user: UserDTO;

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private userService: UsersService) {}

  ngOnInit():void {
    this.sub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      if (this.id != undefined && this.token != undefined)
        this.userService.get("id")
        .subscribe(
          (result: UserDTO) => {
            this.user = result;
          }
        )
      else
        this.router.navigate(['/error']);
    });
  }
  //...
}
```

UserDTO.ts:

```
export interface UserDTO {
    id?: string;
    username?: string;
    cname?: string;
    sname?: string;
    mail?: string;
}
```

On my template I've writeen `user.cname` is shown inside an tag:

```
<header>
  <h3>Hi {{user.cname}}!!!</h3>
</header>
```

Nevertheless, nothing in shown inside `<h3> tag`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your console for any errors.

Comment: There are no related messages on console...